# Getting a blank plot but don't see any problem

Tags: plotting, syntax

I have a problem. I'm trying to plot a function, but I keep getting a blank plot.

[image]

This is function in `InputForm`:

```
(-10000*(2-(25*Cos[500-z])/z)-2*(10000+Cos[500-z]/z)-400*(200-(5*Sin[500-z])/z)-2500*(-((25*Cos[500-z])/z)+((-2+z^2)*Cos[500-z]+2*z*Sin[500-z])/z^3)^2)/(2+2*1[(1/2)*(-((25*Cos[500-z])/z)+((-2+z^2)*Cos[500-z]+2*z*Sin[500-z])/z^3)])
```

When I try to plot it

```
Plot[y, {z, 1, 50}]
```

I'm getting this blank plot:

[image]

Even when I try this, I still get a blank plot.

[image]

Comment: its the square brackets in the denominator

Comment: Typo here `1[...`?

Comment: Look at `y /. z -> 1.0` If an expression doesn't evaluate to a number, it cannot be plotted.

Comment: You have `a[1/2 ( ... )]` in your expression. That's using `a` as a function. I'm guessing you just wanted parentheses there.

Comment: Just to make it clear what all these comments are about: square brackets are reserved for function definitions (and such) and *cannot* be used as parentheses in mathematical computations for the purpose of order of operations.  Parentheses are the only things that can be used for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the square bracket problem is taken care of, a plot can be made, but it is pretty ugly because the function appears to have singularities in the specified domain.

```
f[z_] = 
  (-10000*(2 - (25*Cos[500 - z])/z) - 2*(10000 + Cos[500 - z]/z) - 
     400*(200 - (5*Sin[500 - z])/z) - 
     2500 * 
       (-((25*Cos[500 - z])/z) + 
         ((-2 + z^2)*Cos[500 - z] + 2*z*Sin[500 - z]) / z^3)^2) /
  (2 + 2*(1/2)*(-((25*Cos[500 - z])/z) + 
    ((-2 + z^2)*Cos[500 - z] + 2*z*Sin[500 - z])/z^3))

Plot[f[z], {z, 1, 50}, PlotRange -> {-150000, 150000}]
```

[image: plot]